# Error in React Portals "Target container is not a DOM element"

Tags: reactjs

I am using portals in React and I get error "Target container is not a DOM element".

My code looks so:

```
// I have div inside of component Table where I want to place my portal. 

// that is a part of my table component

 <tr>
      {showCheckbox &&
          <th className="checkbox-table">
            <Checkbox
              indeterminate={isIndeterminate}
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              checked={isChecked}
              disabled={data.every((row) => row.disabled)}
            />
          </th>}
      {headers.map((header) =>
        <th
          key={uid()}
          className="table-cell"
        >
          {header.title}
        </th>
      )}
      {actionRender &&
          <th>
            <div id="table-buttons"></div> // !!! that is div where I want to put my portal  !!!
          </th>
      }
    </tr>
```

```
// this is portal component 

const getPortalElem = () => document.getElementById('table-buttons');

const ButtonsPortal = () => createPortal(<button>Test</button>, getPortalElem());
```

But I have error:

react-dom.development.js:26195 Uncaught Error:

Target container is not a DOM element.

at createPortal$1 (react-dom.development.js:26195:1)

at ButtonsPortal (buttonsPortal.tsx:6:1)

at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)

What can it be and where can I be mistaken ?

Comment: If `actionRender` is `false` then `<div id="table-buttons">` won't be in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, but anyway, if I remove this part of code, the error does not disappear

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on stackblitz?